# How can I put a file in cache in dotnet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization

I have been trying to implement localization in .NET 6.0 via JSON files, and a way of doing that (please note that the resources are provided as JSONs with different formats eg one has nested objects and the other simply key-values) was to implement the *IStringLocalizer* interface and of course every time on lookup in something doesn't exist in the *IDistributedCache* then load the file, parse it accordingly and insert the key-value pair in the distributed cache.

However, upon every entry that doesn't exist in the distributed cache, I will have to load the file (which is IO lookup and I am guessing rather expensive for the app, especially if there is a cache miss frequently) and get the value depending from which file I want to read from.

Is there a way to load the file when startup is called and simply inject it to the localizer extension that I have made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke your service which manage localization in Startup like that

```
app.Services.GetService<IMyLocalizationService>().LoadLocalization()
```

In that moment DI should be builded so you should have access to IDistributedCache